# The TCP client receives the audio stream transmitted by the server. What data structure is used to temporarily store the audio data?

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, audio-player, real-time-data

I have a smart speaker device and a PC. They establish a TCP connection. The smart speaker device keeps recording and transmits audio data to the PC in real time. I now want the PC to store the received audio data in a buffer. At the same time, the audio in the buffer is played.
Now, you may already know the data flow on the PC side.
3 objects, receive audio stream A transmitted from the device side、 audio storage buffer B、audio play area C.

A needs to keep writing data to B,
C needs to constantly read the data in B,

My question now is: What kind of data structure do I use for this buffer(that is B)?
I initially wanted to use the c# queue.look the flowing code.
(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33142/producer-consumer-in-c)
However, I am a little worried. Because the amount of audio data is relatively large, the number of bytes per write B and read B is large. It is about 4KB, `_myQueue.Dequeue` or `_myQueue.Enqueue` can only enter and exit the element one byte at a time. To complete the 4KB read and write, you need to call the above 2 methods frequently.I mean, is there a way to batch write elements and read elements in the queue? so I would like to ask if there is a better design method to implement the audio storage buffer B.

```
private int _count = 1000;
private Queue<byte> _myQueue = new Queue<byte>();
private static object _door = new object();

public void AddItem(byte someItem)
{
    lock (_door)
    {
        while (_myQueue.Count == _count)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(_door);
        }

        _myQueue.Enqueue(someItem);
        Monitor.Pulse(_door);
    }
}

public byte RemoveItem()
{
    byte item;
    lock (_door)
    {
        while (_myQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(_door);
        }

        item = _myQueue.Dequeue();
        Monitor.Pulse(_door);
     }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: _"_myQueue.Enqueue can only enter and exit the element one byte at a time."_ why is that?

Comment: @Fildor I have modified the code again. The reason is that the audio stream is stored in a byte sequence. So,So, I think if the queue is used to store the audio stream, the type of the queue element should be `byte`.

Comment: No it shouldn't. You'll get chunks of `byte[]` from the network. So your queue should deal with `byte[]`. I also suggest you have a look into the TPL DataFlow lib. It will probably make things easier.

Comment: OK，let me have a look.Thank you.